# Mutation changes all values

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to perform a mutation with the following code:

```
set <- c('1 star', '2 stars', '3 stars', '4 stars', '5 stars')
set <- as.data.frame(set)
names(set) <- c('score')
set$score <- as.factor(set$score)
set <- set %>% mutate(score = ifelse(score == '1 star', 1, score))
```

I am expecting the code to change the cells containing the values `1 star` to `1` and if the value is not `1 star` I would like it to stay the way it is. However it seems to change the values in all rows including those cells that have an other value than `1 star`.

What is going wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the values to character while replacing.

```
library(dplyr)

set <- set %>% mutate(score = ifelse(score == '1 star', 1, as.character(score)))

#    score
#1       1
#2 2 stars
#3 3 stars
#4 4 stars
#5 5 stars
```

Comment: I accepted this as the answer as it uses the code I posted myself but anyone ending up here should definitely also look into the answer posted by @sindri_baldur.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined `score` as a factor variable, you can just modify the levels:

```
levels(set$score)[1] <- '1'

#     score
# 1       1
# 2 2 stars
# 3 3 stars
# 4 4 stars
# 5 5 stars
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful with `fct_recode` as it wouldn't change the `factor` to `character`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
set <- set %>%
   mutate(score = fct_recode(score, '1' = '1 star' ))
```

-output

```
set
#    score
#1       1
#2 2 stars
#3 3 stars
#4 4 stars
#5 5 stars
```